# Galois theory or algebraic topology for advanced probability theory

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am an undergraduate student interested in probability theory.I have an option to take either Galois theory or Algebraic topology as part of my course.I want to know which one will be more useful if I wanted to study topics in advanced probability in the future?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It seems like analysis would be more helpful than either of those

Comment: Neither is directly helpful. Both are nice areas, though.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I am already taking analysis.This is in addition to that .

Comment: Does that analysis course you take include Measure Theory? Because this REALLY will help with probability theory.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah I am taking measure theory.

Comment: @smbch Then you're fine. Where I studied Galois Theory is a must for mathematics (undergraduate) students, and a rather beautficul and interesting course. Algebraic topology is way more advanced and specialized, imo.